# Why data augmentation does not improve texture classification accuracy in CNNs?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, conv-neural-network

At the moment, I am using Alexnet to do a classification task.

The size of each input sample is 480*680 like this:

[image]

Using a normal network, fed by cropped inputs of size 256*256 (generated in preprocessing steps) with the batch size of 8, gives me the accuracy rate of 92%.

But, when I  try to generate 5 crops of each (480*680) sample (corners plus a center crop) using the following crop layers:

```
# this is the reference blob of the cropping process which determines cropping size
layer {
  name: "reference-blob"
  type: "Input"
  top: "reference"
  input_param { shape: { dim: 8 dim: 3 dim: 227 dim: 227 } }
}
# upper-left crop
layer{
  name: "crop-1"
  type: "Crop"
  bottom: "data"
  bottom: "reference"
  top: "crop-1"
  crop_param {
      axis: 2
      offset: 1
      offset: 1
    }
}
# upper-right crop
layer{
    name: "crop-2"
    type: "Crop"
    bottom: "data"
    bottom: "reference"
    top: "crop-2"
    crop_param {
        axis: 2
        offset: 1
        offset: 412
    }
}
# lower-left crop
layer{
    name: "crop-3"
    type: "Crop"
    bottom: "data"
    bottom: "reference"
    top: "crop-3"
    crop_param {
        axis: 2
        offset: 252
        offset: 1
    }
}
# lower-right crop
layer{
    name: "crop-4"
    type: "Crop"
    bottom: "data"
    bottom: "reference"
    top: "crop-4"
    crop_param {
        axis: 2
        offset: 252
        offset: 412
    }
}
# center crop
layer{
    name: "crop-5"
    type: "Crop"
    bottom: "data"
    bottom: "reference"
    top: "crop-5"
    crop_param {
        axis: 2
        offset: 127
        offset: 207
    }
}
# concat all the crop results to feed the next layer
layer{
    name: "crop_concat"
    type: "Concat"
    bottom: "crop-1"
    bottom: "crop-2"
    bottom: "crop-3"
    bottom: "crop-4"
    bottom: "crop-5"
    top: "all_crops"
    concat_param {
            axis: 0
    }
}
# generating enough labels for all the crop results
layer{
    name: "label_concat"
    type: "Concat"
    bottom: "label"
    bottom: "label"
    bottom: "label"
    bottom: "label"
    bottom: "label"
    top: "all-labels"
    concat_param {
            axis: 0
    }
}
```

this leads to accuracy rate of 90.6% which is strange.

Any Idea?

Comment: Could you post a sample (480x640) image (before pre-processing)?  There is minimal overlap in the cropped images, so are you sure they all properly represent the desired classification?  Usually, this kind of data augmentation involves generating multiple cropped images that mostly overlap so that the actual object you wish to classify is just translated by a small amount in each cropped image.  If each of the corner images is just a small part of the object you wish to classify, you may be inadvertently making the classification task much more difficult.

Comment: @Aenimated1 Thanks for replay. Actually, they are texture images. I personally think that in this case it cannot be much helpful to generate such cropped versions, but I read somewhere that it can improve the accuracy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typical usage of cropped versions is to get a critical feature in a canonical position for the recognition filters.  For instance, the typical 5-crop method often finds "animal face near the middle of the image" often enough for that to appear as a learning icon 2-4 layers from the end.

Since a texture tends to repeat certain qualities, there's no such advantage in cropping the photos: you present 5 smaller instances of the texture, with relatively larger grain, rather than the full image.

Comment: Sounds reasonable, thank you very much for your clear explanation.